# Enable Einstein Lead Score

Tags: lead-conversion, einstein

I have created 1500 Leads and converted 200 among those leads into Account,Contact and Opportunity but i am unable to enable Einstein Lead Score Feature.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below document. It includes steps for Enable Einstein score feature.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=einstein_sales_setup_enable_lead_insights.htm&type=5